# Add Version info to Android Application

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have notice that quite a few application show version/history informations **before** installation. And I wonder how they do it.

Also, which may or may not be related, Titanium Backup has a full version history on AppBrain. Again I wonder how that is done.

Does anybody know?

Since titanium Backup has a funny star in the URL so normal links won't work, here the link for cut/copy/paste.

```
http://www.appbrain.com/app/titanium-backup-★-root/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup
```

Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you're referring to the change log on some apps. Well, they're cheating - they're making the version log part of the version name.

`android:versionName="1.6.7: Now with fewer crashes and great new features. And much slower than before. How awesome."`

Note that it's now possible to add a changelog when publishing an app, Google enabled that a few days ago. You just enter it on the website where you publish your app and enter the description. That will show up underneath your description, in the same font.

Comment: Thanks. And I like your humour — had a good laugh. And next release is planned for Monday at the new change log feature.

Comment: net.sourceforge.uiq3.fx602p

A first check shows that the version history is picked up by www.appbrain.com, www.androidzoom.com and www.androlib.com.